# unset an array with a specfic condition

Tags: php, arrays

Basically I have this array `$code`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FRANCE
            [1] => 26422
            [2] => 61748
            [3] => 698477678
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => UNITED STATES
            [1] => 545
            [2] => 2648
            [3] => 55697455
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => CANADA
            [1] => 502
            [2] => 1636
            [3] => 15100396
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => GREECE
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 45
            [3] => 458
        )
```

I want to unset all the countries with `$code[$key][1] == 0` so I tired this:

```
$code = array_filter($code, function (array $element) {
return !preg_match('(0)i', $element[1]);
});
```

But it returns all the countries unless the one that has in `$code[$key][1]` 0, Like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FRANCE
            [1] => 26422
            [2] => 61748
            [3] => 698477678
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => UNITED STATES
            [1] => 545
            [2] => 2648
            [3] => 55697455
        )
```

Any how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why using preg. In this way you are filtering all countries which code contains 0. Use simple == instead

Comment: Why not just `return $element[1] !== 0;`? (or `return $element[1] !== "0";` in case of a string). In your sample data this will remove only `GREECE`. The regular expression would `^0$` but don't use regular expressions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without regex:

```
$code = array_filter($code, function (array $element) {
return ($element[1] !== 0);
});
```

With regex (you need to use [anchors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php)):

```
$code = array_filter($code, function (array $element) {
return !preg_match('/^0$/', $element[1]);
});
```

However, I’ll recommend a simple `foreach` loop instead of `array_filter`:

```
foreach($code as $key => $val){
    if($val[1] === 0) unset($code[$key]);
}
```

Comment: +1. Anyway ,`preg_match()` isn't required for this task. The first one should do it. I would change it to `$element[1] !== 0;`, though :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I’ve given the regex solution simply in order to show what went wrong with the original attempt by the author of the question. And I’ve made the change that you’ve suggested here. Thank you very much.

Comment: I know, @Sharanya. That was just meant to be an "FYI" comment for future readers. I see you've added a `foreach` solution as well. That's the best one to use here, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you are trying to remove only Greece, it should be as simple as:

```
$code = array_filter($code, function (array $element) {
    return $element[1] != 0
});
```

The regular expression you are using will remove every country where the key has a 0 in the value, that will exclude also 502 in your example.